# how to search on mongodb by using runcommand

Tags: c#, mongodb, full-text-search, nosql

This is my code... but runcommand doesn't get any results

Notice : "title" is an indexed field

```
        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]);

        var server = mongoClient.GetServer();
        mongodatabase = server.GetDatabase("Htmlattachment2");
        MongoCollection<Department> attachments = mongodatabase.GetCollection<Department>("attachment2");

        attachments.EnsureIndex(new IndexKeysBuilder().Ascending("title"));
        attachments.Insert(new BsonDocument("title", "The quick brown fox"));

        var t = attachments.GetIndexes().ToList();
        //foreach (Attachements emp in attachments.FindAll())
        //{ }

        var textSearchCommand = new CommandDocument
         {
            { "text","title" },
            { "search", textBox1.Text }
        };

        var commandResult = mongodatabase.RunCommand(textSearchCommand);

        var response = commandResult.Response["results"].AsBsonArray;
        foreach (BsonDocument result in response)
        {
            // process result
        }
```

Comment: Please, clarify your issue. What do you want to do, what is your expected result, what goes wrong and where if it does? Also, please, do fix the code [formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in your question.

Comment: Have you considered using AsQueryable instead and using Linq to search?

Comment: mclaassen but how to search in mongodb by linq ??

Comment: My expected result if i insert word like "fox" in textbox1 ,get right search result but i didn't get any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier if you just used LINQ to perform queries. There is a tutorial on how use LINQ with MongoDB [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/). Note that the MongoDB C# driver translates the LINQ queries to run on the database as native Mongo queries.

Comment: Thank you ^_^ Thank you :) Thank you Eng mclaassen :)